# DotLiquid - access an collection element via a string indexer?

Tags: c#, collections, element, dotliquid

Is it possible to access a collection item by a string reference instead of an index offset for DotLiquid?

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name;
    public object Value;

    public MyItem(string Name, object Value)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
}

  public class MyCollection : List<MyItem>
{
    public MyCollection()
    {
        this.Add(new MyItem("Rows", 10));
        this.Add(new MyItem("Cols", 20));
    }

    public MyItem this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Find(m => m.Name == name);
        }
    }
}
```

So in normal c# if I create an instance of the MyCollection class I can access the elements like this

```
MyCollection col =new MyCollection();
col[1] or col["Rows"]
```

Can I access via the name element col["Rows"] in a DotLiquid template? If so how do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. First, define a `Drop` class like this:

```
public class MyCollectionDrop : Drop
{
  private readonly MyCollection _items;

  public MyCollectionDrop(MyCollection items)
  {
    _items = items;
  }

  public override object BeforeMethod(string method)
  {
    return _items[method];
  }
}
```

Then, in the code that renders your template, add an instance of it to the context:

```
template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { my_items = new MyCollectionDrop(myCollection) }));
```

Finally, access it like this in your template:

```
{{ my_items.rows.name }}
```

"rows" will be passed as-is to `MyCollectionDrop.BeforeMethod` as the `method` argument.

Note that you'll also need to make `MyItem` inherit from `Drop`, to be able to access its properties. Or write a `MyItemDrop` class like this:

```
public class MyItemDrop : Drop
{
  private readonly MyItem _item;

  public MyItemDrop(MyItem item)
  {
    _item = item;
  }

  public string Name
  {
    get { return _item.Name; }
  }

  public string Value
  {
    get { return _item.Value; }
  }
}
```

and then change `MyCollectionDrop.BeforeMethod` to this:

```
public override object BeforeMethod(string method)
{
  return new MyItemDrop(_items[method]);
}
```